# How to make my dropdownlist have always the same index selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So I want to make my dropdownlist to have always the same index selected, for example I have a gridview and I have a pager on it, if I change the page the index I had in my dropdownlist resets and I can give other example, I have a search textbox in my page and if I search something on it when I press enter the dropdownlist resets once again. How can I make my dropdownlist to have always the same selected index?

asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server"
                    DataKeyNames="No_" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Style="color: Black; border-collapse: collapse; margin-right: auto; display: table; text-align: center;" OnPageIndexChanging="MyGrid_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanged="MyGrid_PageIndexChanged" PageSize="10" AllowCustomPaging="False">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="No_" HeaderText="No_Encomenda" />


                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

cs

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString);
        List<string> MySelected;
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonBack.Visible = false;
        //GridView1.Visible = false;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select bl from booking", con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("-");

        if(IsPostBack == false)
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(sdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }

        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            MySelected = new List<string>();
            LoadGrid();
            ViewState["MySelected"] = MySelected;
        }
        else
        {
            MySelected = (List<string>)ViewState["MySelected"];
        }
        string user = Convert.ToString(Session["user"]);

        username.Text = user;

        if (Session["user"] == null || Session["login"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            refreshdata();
            refreshdata();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
        public void LoadGrid()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [EncomendaTEMP]", con);
            {

                DataTable rst = new DataTable();
                rst.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                MyGrid.DataSource = rst;
                MyGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
public void refreshdata()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [EncomendaTEMP]", con);
            {

                DataTable rst = new DataTable();
                rst.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                MyGrid.DataSource = rst;
                MyGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the code which populates the data in the dropwonlist? Can you share the code of `page_load` from code behind?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya sure

Comment: You are loading data in dropdownlist inside `page_load`. That resets the dropdownlist to the default selection. You need place the code which loads the dropdownllist, inside the `if (IsPostBack == false)` block. So that the Dropdown will be populated only on the first load. The postback will keep the data in the dropdownlist and the selection will be maintained.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so i just have to add the `if (IsPostBack == false)`

Comment: Yes.. you need to load the dropdown inside `if(IsPostBack==false)`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya now when i search something or if i change the grid page it stills disappear and the dropdownlist doesnt load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234155/discussion-between-miguel-araujo-and-chetan-ranpariya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Page_Load` code, I see that you are loading data in dropdownlist. When the page is submitted, `Page_Load` will execute and it will reload the data in the dropdown list. That's why selection goes off.

You should load the data in the dropdown list only during first load of the page. As you are doing with `LoadGrid()`. During post back the data of the dropdown and selection will be maintained if you don't reload them.

So I suggest following code change for loading data in dropdown list.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select bl from booking", con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("-");
        
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
       DropDownList1.Items.Add(sdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
    
    MySelected = new List<string>();
    LoadGrid();
    ViewState["MySelected"] = MySelected;
}
else
{
    MySelected = (List<string>)ViewState["MySelected"];
}
```

I hope this will help you solve your problem.